# In survey sampling, have calibration margins to be known (estimated with 0 variance)?

Tags: sampling, survey, bias, calibration, design-based-inference

Calibration estimators in survey sampling (as defined by [Deville and Särndal](http://www.stat.unipg.it/~giovanna/didattica/teo/Deville_sarndal.pdf), and implemented for example in the SAS macro "Calmar") generalize many other calibration estimators, including post-stratification, when calibration is done using totals of dummies indicating whether each unit belongs to the given post-stratum.

An interesting property about post-stratification estimators is that they are (strictly) unbiased, ***except*** when calibration is done using totals not *known with certainty*, but *estimated* with a slight error $e = \hat{T(X)} - T(X)$. In this case, bias of the post-stratification estimator is a function of $e$, and ***does not decrease with sample size*** (i.e. you can't say the post-stratification estimator is "asymptotically unbiased")

By inference, one could imagine that calibration could only be done using totals known without variance, i.e. computed using the sample frame or a census.

However, it seems that very often calibration estimators are used even when only estimated margins are known. People seem rather happy with it, as long as sample size for the estimation of the margin is significantly higher than sample size of the survey they're trying to calibrate. Pascal Ardilly, in his book [Les techniques de sondage](http://www.amazon.fr/Les-techniques-sondage-Pascal-Ardilly/dp/2710808471) (in French, Technip, 2006), says that "you can show that calibration estimation is still asymptotically unbiased when margin is not known, but estimated", but does not explain how this can be done.

Has anyone got ideas on how to prove this result ? Am I the only one the be bugged by the apparent paradox with the bias of the post-stratification estimator ? Maybe the proof brings out a term that cannot be simplified if all variables are categorical and totals for each modality are known (although this would *still* bug me...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that a proof of asymptotic unbiasedness applies only to the *double* process: 1) estimate margins, with bias going to zero asymptotically; and 2) calibrate to these estimates.

Comment: It's probably what Ardilly meant indeed ! I'm still a little confused, because even if the process you describe truly is unbiased, it seems to me that MSEs can add up dramatically in this case. For what I've seen so far, people working with calibrated estimators just assume unbiasedness (from Deville and Särndal's theorem, i.e. _not_ the 2-step process you describe) and move on...

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of estimators calibrated to estimated control totals has been studied already, see [Dever and Valliant 2010](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Richard_Valliant/publication/228627074_A_comparison_of_variance_estimators_for_poststratification_to_estimated_control_totals/links/5401ed7c0cf23d9765a524a3.pdf) (which is the most technical part of Jill Dever's dissertation). They derive the bias explicitly, discuss the (somewhat weird) conditions under which the bias is small, and provide additional variance terms necessary to account for uncertainty in the control totals.

Comment: Very interesting article ! Though I'm surprised the authors don't insist on the formula : $Bias \approx t_y \dfrac{N_b}{N}$ ($N_b$ being the the estimated margin and $N$ the true margin, assuming there's no coverage bias). After all, it means using estimated margins leads to biased calibrated estimators. And in practice, it is impossible to compute $\dfrac{N_b}{N}$, as surveys are only done once.

Comment: A related paper, though not about calibration: Little, Roderick J. A., and Mei-Miau Wu. 1991. Models for Contingency Tables with Known Margins when Target and Sampled Populations Differ. Journal of the American Statistical Association 86, no. 413: 87-95.  See the abstract at: http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/citedby/10.1080/01621459.1991.10475007